# CallScreeningService: Why are rejected calls not being added to the native call log?

Tags: android

I'm developing a call blocker that I want to work on API 29. To block calls on API 29, I have a class called CallScreenService that extends CallScreeningService. The issue I'm having is that calls I'm rejecting don't get added to the phone's native call log. I want the user to be able to see the rejected numbers. Below is my endCall function:

```
private void endCall(Call.Details callDetails) {
    CallResponse.Builder response = new CallResponse.Builder();
    response.setRejectCall(true);
    response.setDisallowCall(true);
    response.setSkipCallLog(false);
    respondToCall(callDetails, response.build());
}
```

The function that I have trouble understanding is the [setSkipCallLog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService.CallResponse.Builder.html#setSkipCallLog(boolean)). I've tried setting it to true/false and neither way adds it to the call log.

Edit:
It seems like this is a known issue, although it still hasn't been fixed:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130081372

Comment: Is it not appearing in a particular app that displays calls, or is it not showing if you programatically query the call log?  In the first case, it could be the app filtering it, which would be solved by changing the app.

Comment: @GabeSechan It's not displaying in the default call log that comes installed of the phone. I'm using this on an emulator.

Comment: no such thing. Oems can and do install different call logs. That app isn't insured to be installed on any device. Which is why I asked if it's there when you query programmatically. If some particular call log app chooses to filter it out, there's nothing you can do to prevent it

Comment: @GabeSechan I had to do some testing on it. I can still query the numbers that get blocked by the app, even if they're not displayed. I'm not sure I fully understand your question though. Are you saying that some apps naturally filter numbers and it's out of my control? When I block numbers using endCall above, the numbers get blocked and don't get added to the call log, but when I don't use endcall the numbers get added to the call log. I believe I have control over if they're shown in the native call log with setSkipCallLog but I'm unsure how it works.